# Using Clone for addInstance on MySQL Innodb Cluster uses 100% Memory

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, mysql-innodb-cluster, group-replication

When trying to add a new node to a MySQL Innodb cluster using Cluster.addInstance() and selecting the Clone option, within 2 or 3 minutes the donor nodes memory usages hits 100% on a server with 36Gb of memory. At 100% memory usage the server becomes unresponsive and the recipient server moves to another server in the cluster, tries to clone, and the memory usage of the 2nd donor hits 100%. The entire cluster is degraded in under 10 min and unavailable.

This is on a Production server so the consequences here are pretty devastating.

I’m running MySQL 8.0.36 on Debian 12 Bookworm.

I have not encountered this problem setting up a test cluster with a small amount of data, which I have done several times to ensure I’m doing everything correctly. However on my Production server with about 125Gb of data, this problem occurs consistently.

The process chews through 10Gb+ of memory in just a few minutes, which doesn't seem normal. Killing the Clone query doesn't appear to stop the memory consumption.

I cannot find any information regarding the memory requirements for Clone.

Has anyone else experienced this problem or know what the cause might be?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you made any tuning changes to my.cnf?  If so, let's see them.  Also, how much RAM?

Comment: Please give us the commands you issued and any messages back from the server - you're basically saying I did something and there's a problem - what, **exactly** did you do?